# Mapping through a list of elements to change a string value

Tags: sesam

I want to iterate through a list for each element in the list, and then when matching on a given string - convert that string to a target string.

Use Case:
List manipulation

I've tried different functions i.e. case, case-eq etc. albeit none of the mentioned functions seem to solve the issue.

Pipe Config:

```
{
  "_id": "jonas-testing-manipulated-properties",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "jonas-testing"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "country",
          ["list", "Norway", "Denmark", "Sweden"]
        ],
        ["add", "Country Abbreviation",
          ["case-eq", "_T.country", "Norway", "NO", "Sweden", "SE", "Other"]
        ],
        ["add", "Country Abbreviation with mapping",
          ["map",
            ["case-eq", "_T.country", "Norway", "NO", "Sweden", "SE", "Other"], "_T.country"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Country Abbreviation": "Other",
    "Country Abbreviation with mapping": [
      "Other",
      "Other",
      "Other"
    ],
    "_deleted": false,
    "_hash": "f2ed1ca17e97917245d6b465ca7ed7ae",
    "_id": "1",
    "_previous": 71,
    "_ts": 1559888447704105,
    "_updated": 72,
    "convert-to-int": "~f1.5",
    "country": [
      "Norway",
      "Denmark",
      "Sweden"
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Result

```
[
  {
    "Country Abbreviation": "Other",
    "Country Abbreviation with mapping": [
      "NO",
      "Other",
      "SE"
    ],
    "_deleted": false,
    "_hash": "f2ed1ca17e97917245d6b465ca7ed7ae",
    "_id": "1",
    "_previous": 71,
    "_ts": 1559888447704105,
    "_updated": 72,
    "convert-to-int": "~f1.5",
    "country": [
      "Norway",
      "Denmark",
      "Sweden"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `map` function you need to reference the `_.` variable instead of `_T.country`. This should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the code solution for future ref:

Obs. Added "int to string" manipulation as well, using the same functions.

Refactored Code

```
["add", "_age",
   ["list", 20, 18, 14, 13, 22, 28, 12, 11, 12]
],
["add", "_country",
   ["list", "Norway", "Denmark", "Sweden"]
],
["add", "Country Abbreviation with mapping",
   ["map",
      ["case-eq", "_.", "Norway", "NO", "Sweden", "SE", "DK"], "_T._country"]
],
["add", "String Representation of int age list",
   ["map",
      ["if",
         ["gte", "_.", 18], "jedi", "padawan"], "_T._age"]
]
```